# How to return different types from an if and its corresponding else in DAML?

Tags: daml

Currently in DAML if and else condition would expect to return same output.

How can I return different types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have to return the same type from both branches. If you want to return different types what you can do is to instead use `Either A B` from both branches and use `Left a` in one case and `Right b` in the other. So for a full example, let’s say you have an `if` and an `Int` in the first branch and a `Text` in the second you can do something like the following:

```
ifClause : Either Int String
ifClause = if cond then Left 1 else Right "foobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

but this 
if else return makes the **template to archive it**,without allowing other data to be execute